# How to compare a revision to its previous revision using CVS diff?

Tags: diff, cvs

I am currently analyzing some CVS projects. Suppose I want to compare Foo.c (revision 5) to its previous revision (revision 4) and output the diff, can I use CVS diff to achieve this? (No working copy involved)

I know that SVN diff has an option --change(-c) that can achieve this, a command like:

```
$ svn diff -c 5 Foo.c
```

can automatically compare revision 5 of Foo.c to its previous revision.

I just wonder whether CVS diff has similar options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

`cvs diff -c -r 5 -r 4 Foo.c`

Comment: Yes I realized this usage. However, sometimes the CVS revision number could be something like 1.240, then is the previous revision number 1.239? Or 1.230? I just feel that manually determining previous revision number may introduce mistakes (especially for projects that I'm not familiar with), so I hope that the CVS diff can automatically handle that.

Comment: I don't think CVS diff has this functionality. The revisions here are file based, and not on a particular tree. This has been sirted out in SVN although. If you involve working copy, then the diff with previous version would be easy. Try using `PREV`